# Java code example for read only interface pattern

Tags: java

Consider the following code for a read only interface pattern in Java:

```java
package package2;

public interface AccountsReadOnly {
    public String getValue();
}
```

```java
package package1;

import package2.AccountsReadOnly;

class Accounts implements AccountsReadOnly {
    private String name;

    public Accounts() {
        name = "unknown";
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setValue(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
package package1;

public class Manager {
    Accounts allAccess;
    public Manager() {}
}
```

```java
package package2;

public class Employee {
    public AccountsReadOnly accountReadOnly;
    public Employee() {}
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Manager m = new Manager();
        Employee e = new Employee();
        Accounts a = new Accounts();
        m.allAccess = a;
        m.allAccess.setValue("Andrew");
        System.out.println(m.allAccess.getValue());
        e.accountReadOnly = a;
        System.out.println(e.accountReadOnly.getValue());
    }
}
```

I can't understand this line as this is the first time for me to see this format:

```java
m.allAccess.setValue("Andrew");
```

Is it possible to use instead of this line since they have the same reference?

```java
m.setValue("Andrew");
```

Is `m.allAccess` a reference of the object?

Comment: Hey - your code is extremely hard to read right now because of strange indentation. If you fix it, you'll like get better responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use instead of this line since they have the same reference?

no, `m.setValue("Andrew");` does not work, because the `Manager`-class has no function `setValue`

> Is `m.allAccess` a reference of the object?

yes, `allAccess` references the `Account`-object which is set in this line: `m.allAccess = a;`

The `getValue` and `setValue` methods should really be named `getName`and `setName`, because that what they do. `setValue`should return a value, e.g. the account's balance.

Also `name`is not read-only if you have a setter for it.